# Redirect to page when value is null in another table laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I'm trying to redirect the user to another page if my additional_infos table contain some stuff that are empty in this case, contact, name and address.

I've done something like that for now:

But it keep redirecting me to the other page even though the contact, name and address is filled. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

```
public function test(Request $request){
    $additional_info = DB::table('additional_infos') ->where('address',NULL)->orWhere('name', NULL)->orWhere('number')->get();
    //request input //ignore this part
    if( $additional_info) {
        return redirect(url('/user/showupdate6/'.$id->id.'/edit6') );
    } else {
        return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```

I want it to redirect me to home page if my data name, contact and address is filled. If my data name, contact and address is null I want it to redirect me to this url, `url('/user/showupdate6/'.$id->id.'/edit6')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will never get null so that you can test it in if like this `if( $additional_info)` it will alawys evaluate to true, **because** it will always return a collection even if there is no elements that fulfil the conditions it will return a empty collection not null.

You have three choices :

- Use `->get()` and add `->count()` in the if statment `if($additional_info->count())`
- Replace `->get()` by `->first()` and leave `if($additional_info)`
- Replace `->get()` by `->count()` and `if($additional_info > 0)`

Try it using `whereNull` and `orWhereNull` like this :

```
public function test(Request $request){
    $additional_info = DB::table('additional_infos') 
                            ->whereNull('address')
                            ->orWhereNull('name')
                            ->orWhereNull('number')
                            ->get();
    //request input //ignore this part
    if( $additional_info->count())
        return redirect(url('/user/showupdate6/'.$id->id.'/edit6') );
    else{
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: It still redirect me back to the showupdate url part... when it should have been home url. Did I do something wrong in the if else statement part?

Comment: try my last update with `->count()` in the if statment

Comment: Could you explain why do I have to use count in this scenario? I don't quite get it

Comment: Ohh I understand now. Thank you so much for helping :)

Comment: Happy to help :) I forgot to add an other way to do it is replace `->get()` by `->first()` and leave `if($additional_info)` it will work also see the edit ;)

Comment: hi sorry to disturb you, but for some reason when I try to use your code for another purpose it not working the way I want, could you help me take a look if possible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901006/showing-a-message-if-data-is-null-laravel#47901096

Comment: so sorry about that, I just saw it

Answer (score 0):

Try transform your query to SQL to check what are you doing with database first

```
$additional_info = DB::table('additional_infos')->where('address',NULL)->orWhere('name', NULL)->orWhere('number')->toSql();
dd($additional_info);
```

Comment: "select * from `additional_infos` where `address` is null or `name` is null or `number` is null" this is return