# Redirect page when value is 0 or null laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I'm trying to redirect the user to another page if my additional_infos table contain some stuff that are empty in this case, contact, name, Salutation and address.

I've have something like that now: (based from my previous question that I asked, [Redirect to page when value is null in another table laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883508/redirect-to-page-when-value-is-null-in-another-table-laravel))

But it keep redirecting me to the other page even though the contact,Salutation, name and address is filled. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

The Salutation is in 0 instead of NULL because I am using dropdown list, so if I were to leave it blank it will return 0

```
public function test(Request $request){
    $additional_info = DB::table('additional_infos') 
                            ->whereNull('address')
                            ->orWhereNull('name')
                            ->orWhereNull('number')
                            ->orWhere('Salutation', 0)
                            ->get();
    //request input //ignore this part
    if( $additional_info->count())
        return redirect(url('/user/showupdate6/'.$id->id.'/edit6') );
    else{
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

I want it to redirect me to home page if my data name,Salutation, contact and address is filled. If my data name, contact and address is null I want it to redirect me to this url, `url('/user/showupdate6/'.$id->id.'/edit6')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `empty()`.

```
if( empty($additional_info->count())){
    return redirect(url('/user/showupdate6/'.$id->id.'/edit6') );
}else{
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: It still return back to the showupdate url, and not home

Comment: can you `var_dump($additional_info->count());`before the if statement and tell me the output./

Comment: I put before the if statement but nothing happens, it just redirect me to the showupdate url

Comment: i forgot, also put die(); after var_dump so it wont redirect to another page

Comment: It is still redirecting... Put it before the if statement right?

Comment: Yes before if statement, You may also try changing the orWhere('Salutation', 0) to where only if you're looking with a salutation 0 only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161561/discussion-between-bluetree-and-dkna).

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again but I forgot to check the part where it will redirect to the showupdate page, it seem like when my data contain 0 it didn't redirect to the showupdate page

Answer (score 1):

Use this code :

```
public function test(Request $request){
         $additional_info = DB::table('additional_infos') 
                        ->whereNull('address')
                        ->orWhereNull('name')
                        ->orWhereNull('number')
                        ->orWhere('Salutation', 0)
                        ->get();
         //request input //ignore this part
        if( $additional_info->count() > 0)
           return redirect('/home');
        else{
           return redirect(url('/user/showupdate6/'.$id->id.'/edit6') );
         }
```

Comment: I used whereNull instand of orWhereNull because you want if data name,Salutation, contact AND address are filled... redirect to homepage...

Comment: I want if Salutation or name or contact or address are not filled redirect to url showupdate if they are all filled redirect them to home page

Comment: Okay, you say Or ! let me one time to look again your code

Comment: What do you mean portion of code? You mean the answer you gave? I just change the part count > 0 and orWhere to where

Comment: I edited the answer... look it and give me your feedback !

Comment: Yup this work as well sorry just now I was testing on the wrong page that why nothing was really happening but I tried your code as well and it work. Thanks a lot for your help :)