# Showing a message if data is null laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show a message in my blade where if my address, name or number is null say this fields are empty please fill them up, if there are filled already, just don't display anything.

Currrently I did like this, but in the blade.php. Previously I had already asked something similar but this time I want to show a message. I tried following the question that I asked but for some reason it keep showing the message "please fill them up" even though my data contain values inside the database.

[Redirect to page when value is null in another table laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883508/redirect-to-page-when-value-is-null-in-another-table-laravel/47883640?noredirect=1#comment82734431_47883640)

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
     $additional_info = DB::table('additional_informations') 
                            ->whereNull('address')
                            ->orWhereNull('name')
                            ->orWhereNull('number')
                            ->get();
        if( $additional_info->count())
        echo "test";

 ?>
```

Comment: Both is fine I just want to tell user to fill up the form @JamesRiady

Comment: The problem now is that the wrong message is being shown so I am unsure of what to do

Comment: lets think about your code.. If you have 2 records data in your table additional information, with null address.. when you count it... it will display count = 2.. if count > 0 then show the message

Comment: But I am unsure of showing nothing if there is no null information, how do I do that

Comment: I tried using where('address' , '==' , NULL) but it doesn't work @JamesRiady that was just a try only

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a route like this :

```
Route::get('/userAddInfo/{id}/AddInfo','VerificationController@AddInfo');
```

You can get the user id in the method as parameter then use it in the query like this :

```
public function AddInfo($id) {
    $additional_info = DB::table('additional_informations')
                            ->where('user_id', $id)
                            ->where(function ($query) {
                                    $query->whereNull('EC_address')
                                          ->orWhereNull('EC_name')
                                          ->orWhereNull('EC_number');
                                })
                            ->get(); 
    return view('AddVerificationInfo',compact('id','additional_info')); 
}
```

And in the view :

```
@if($additional_info->count())
    "Please fill this up"
@endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are working on the index.blade.php page here how it goes

InformationController - Controller

```
public function index($id) {
         $additional_info = DB::table('additional_informations') 
                            ->whereNull('address')
                            ->orWhereNull('name')
                            ->orWhereNull('number')
                            ->where('id', '=', $id)
                            ->first();
          return view('index', compact('id','additional_info '));

}
```

index.blade.php - View

```
<div>
    @if(count($additional_info) > 0)
        Here are the rows that has Null values: <br/>
             Please go back and fill up the values of
             @if($additional_info->EC_name == null)
                 EC_name 
             @endif
             @if($additional_info->EC_relationship== null)
                 EC_relationship
             @endif
             @if($additional_info->EC_address== null)
                 EC_address
             @endif
             // and so on. There is a shorter way but I'm not in my laptop right now. But this should work fine

    @else
         {{ $id }} has no Null data found
    @endif
</div>
```

Tell me if you need more help on this part. Cheers

Comment: may I know what is the structure of your array/object.
Basically it already works, just not displaying the object you want

try inserting <?php print_r($additional_info); ?> then paste the result here

Comment: put it bellow the "Data Found". It will return an array or that contains the data that was return from your query

Comment: Bro, put the result here. I know that it returns 4 different result, we need to know the structure of your data so that we can output the field to let you know which are the empty ones

Comment: Please see my updates above, It will show you the ID of the row that has null data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161590/discussion-between-rey-norbert-besmonte-and-dkna).

Answer (score 1):

```
/* In controller */

$additional_info = DB::table('additional_informations') 
                            ->whereNull('address')
                            ->orWhereNull('name')
                            ->orWhereNull('number')
                            ->get()->toArray(); // to convert output into array 

/* In view (blade template) */

@if(!empty($additional_info))

echo "<pre>";
print_r($additional_info);

@else 

echo "No data found";

@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move your logic into a controller, then pass a variable like `$noAdditionalInfo` to the view

Then you can use blade tags:

```
@if($noAdditionalInfo)
    <!-- html goes here -->
@endIf
```

Comment: Hi I have tried your method but it still return the message. Could I have done something wrong in the query?